# How to calculate the gradient of this obejctive function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, gradient-descent

I have this optimization problem: $$\min_v \sum_{v(i)v(j) \neq0} dist(\vec{x}_i,\vec{x}_j) , ~~ i=1...N$$
where $v$ is $N \times 1$.

Meaning that i calculate the sum of distances between pairs of $(\vec{x}_i,\vec{x}_j)$ if their relevant entries in $v$ are both non-zero.

Q:My question is how to calculate the gradient of the above objective function respect to $v$? or is it at all possible?

Comment: There is a discontinuity at $v(i)v(j) = 0$, which means the derivative does not exist everywhere. Where it exists, it is 0. You may want to resort to mixed integer linear optimization to solve this problem. If $N$ is small, you can also solve it with brute force.

Comment: @LinAlg: so how to approach this optimization problem?

Comment: What is $N$? Why is $v$ continuous instead of binary? Assuming distance is nonnegative, why not take $v=0$?